# In Django, how to determine if translation for a given text is available?

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I would like to determine, if there's a translation to current language for a given string. I'd like to write something like:

```
if not translation_available("my string"):
    log_warning_somewhere()
```

I didn't find anything appropriate. The `ugettext` function just returns the translation or the original string (if the translation isn't available) but without any option to determine if the translation is there or isn't.

Thanks.

Comment: You can monkey patch the NullTranslationCatalog's gettext method, I believe.  Once you've reached this catalog, it means you've bypassed all translations, so you can log your warning right there.   Probably best to submit a patch to Django :)

Comment: It's more efficient than the accepted answer for sure (also, I suspect if you use the mofile instead of the pofile, that would be more efficient too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use polib for that: https://bitbucket.org/izi/polib/wiki/Home

Something along those (untested) lines of code:

```
import polib
po = polib.pofile('path/your_language.po')
text == 'Your text'
is_translated = any(e for e in po if e.msgid == text and (not e.translated() or 'fuzzy' in e.flags) and not e.obsolete)
```

This will give True when an *active* translation is available. 'e.translated()' alone returns True for both, fuzzy and/or obsolete phrases, too.

Comment: `for e in po.translated_entries()`... would be more efficient perhaps?

Comment: Will this not return true for any matching entry that isn't translated?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking for a hacky solution:

```
from django.utils.translation import trans_real

def custom_gettext(msg):
    # Returns None when a data translation is not found
    return trans_real._active.value._catalog.get(msg)  # noqa

if custom_gettext("my string") is None:
    log_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, as you say, ugettext will return the original string if no translation is available, can't you just compare the returned value with the original to see if they're identical?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not what I've been looking for. In some languages some strings may be translated as English strings intentionally, while in other languages, that tend to translate everything, the translation exists. So this would give a false  warning. I would like to detect whether the translation is missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
def translation_available(msg): return ugettext(msg) == msg
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I wrote above: if I translate the string as English intentionally, this will give a false warning.

Comment: This relies too heavily on coincidences.

Answer (score 0):

Szymon's solution worked for me after a minor change:

```
from django.utils.translation import trans_real

def custom_gettext(msg):
    # Returns None when a data translation is not found
    return trans_real.catalog()._catalog.get(msg)  # noqa

if custom_gettext("my string") is None:
    log_something()
```